# Count Items based on filters and display them in webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, web-part

Can you please help? I don't know what i am doing wrong here. Also i have column name that has spaces "File Status". How to write that in the code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            $.ajax({
                       url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('VolunteerMasterList')/items",
                       method: "GET",
                       headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                       success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                                    var sum =0;
                                    var sum1 =0;
                                    var sum2 =0;
                                    var sum3 =0;
                                    $.each(data.d.results, function(item){
                                        if(item.City === "Earth")
                                          sum++;
                                        if(item.VolunteerMasterListFileStatus === "Closed")
                                          sum1++;
                                        if(item.VolunteerMasterListFileStatus === "Partial")
                                          sum2++;
                                        if(item.VolunteerMasterListFileStatus === "Special Project")
                                          sum3++;
                                    });                             
                            }
    document.getElementById("myelement").innerHTML=sum;
                      },
                      error: function (data) {
                          alert("Error: "+ data);
                     }
              });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Field static name.

Sample script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            $.ajax({
                       url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('VolunteerMasterList')/items",
                       method: "GET",
                       headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                       success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                                    var sum =0;
                                    var sum1 =0;
                                    var sum2 =0;
                                    var sum3 =0;
                                    $.each(data.d.results, function(index,item){
                                        if(item.City === "Earth")
                                          sum++;
                                        if(item.File_x0020_Status === "Closed")
                                          sum1++;
                                        if(item.File_x0020_Status === "Partial")
                                          sum2++;
                                        if(item.File_x0020_Status === "Special Project")
                                          sum3++;
                                    }); 
                                    console.log(sum);
                                    console.log(sum1);
                                    console.log(sum2);
                                    console.log(sum3);
                            }
                        document.getElementById("myelement").innerHTML=sum;
                      },
                      error: function (data) {
                          alert("Error: "+ data);
                     }
              });
    </script>

    <div id="myelement"></div>
```

This is i am doing finally

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            $.ajax({
                       url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Volunteer%20Master%20List')/items",
                       method: "GET",
                       headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                       success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                                    var sum =0;
                                    var sum1 =0;
                                    var sum2 =0;
                                    var sum3 =0;
                                    $.each(data.d.results, function(index,item){
                                        if(item.File_x0020_Status  === "Active")
                                          sum++;
                                        if(item.File_x0020_Status === "Closed")
                                          sum1++;
                                        if(item.File_x0020_Status === "Partial")
                                          sum2++;
                                        if(item.File_x0020_Status === "Special Project")
                                          sum3++;
                                    }); 
                                    console.log(sum);
                                    console.log(sum1);
                                    console.log(sum2);
                                    console.log(sum3);
                            }
                        document.getElementById("myelement").innerHTML=sum;
document.getElementById("myelement1").innerHTML=sum1;
document.getElementById("myelement2").innerHTML=sum2;
document.getElementById("myelement3").innerHTML=sum3;
                      },
                      error: function (data) {
                          alert("Error: "+ data);
                     }
              });
    </script>

    <div id="myelement"></div>
<div id="myelement1"></div>
<div id="myelement2"></div>
<div id="myelement3"></div>
```

Comment: The script works perfectly fine. Thanks for helping out. The only problem i have that there are 319 entries but the total item count for each shows 21,77,2,0

Comment: Any idea please why my Totals are not matching,